# Реализация индексатора бинарного дерева поиска

Tags: c#, алгоритм, структуры-данных

Возникла проблема с реализацией индексатора бинарного дерева поиска.
Единственное, что нашел в интернете - необходимо хранить в каждой вершине размер его поддерева. Что делать с этой информацией не могу придумать. Требуемая сложность алгоритма O(h), где h -высота дерева.

Comment: а что вы сделали самостоятельно?

Comment: Конкретно по этой проблеме на данный момент ничего придумать не смог. Не могу понять сам принцип поиска элемента в дереве по его индексу.
А если в общем, то реализована структура данных со стандартным набором методов (вставка, удаление, поиск элемента в дереве, возврат всех элементов в порядке возрастания)

Comment: поиск по дереву идет по ответам, следовательно у вас система иерархична, и в простом случае это ответы да и нет, если нет ветвь 1, если да ветвь 2, так пока не будет найден нужный узел. Самое главное как вы представите сам узел.

Comment: Бинарные деревья могут быть сбалансированы или нет. Сбалансированных деревьев несколько видов. У вас какое?

Comment: @Monomax Возможно я ошибаюсь, но это больше походит на поиск нужного узла в дереве. Или этот же принцип подходит для поиска узла по индексу?

Comment: @Vasek Извините за глупый вопрос, я только лишь начинаю изучать подобные структуры данных, но какие в принципе бывают виды сбалансированных деревьев?

Comment: Ну обычно начинают с [АВЛ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) или [Красно-чёрного](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)

Comment: @Vasek исходя из этих ссылок мой случай - Красно-чёрное дерево

Comment: Славно. Вы его сделали в классическом виде? Где код?

Comment: Александр, Вы дерево поиска умеете использовать по назначению (для поиска значения)? Попробуйте подумать, как вычислить индекс произвольной вершины, если для каждой вершины дерева известен размер её поддерева, а для рассматриваемой вершины - известен путь от корня дерева к этой вершине. Сумев вычислить индекс, Вы увидите, что здесь можно применить уже знакомый алгоритм.

Comment: @Vasek Я не понимаю, зачем вам код или вообще какие-либо детали. Задача идейная: получить индекс элемента за О(h); алгоритм будет тот же самый для любой балансировки, потому что все бинарные деревья поиска обладают одним основным свойством, которое и позволяет решать такие задачи.

Comment: Александр, задача решается также, как и большинство задач на деревья: рекурсией. Нужно помнить главное свойство БДП: все элементы слева меньше данного, все элементы справа больше данного. Если искомый элемент больше корня, идём вправо и добавляем к ответу {размер левого поддерева + 1}; если меньше, идём влево и ничего не добавляем.

Comment: @Александр у вас только с поиском возникают сложности?